# Где находятся сегменты из списка воспроизведения HLS?

Tags: аудио, hls, m3u

У меня есть следующий список воспроизведения HLS: https://digitacdn.akamaized.net/hls/live/629243/radiosuomipop/master-128000.m3u8. 
Он содержит ссылки на сегменты аудио файла в кодировке AAC.
Содержимое файла:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
## Created with Z/IPStream R/2 v1.03.23
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2984548
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2018-10-23T11:44:44Z
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01493/seg128000-02984548.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01493/seg128000-02984549.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01493/seg128000-02984550.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01493/seg128000-02984551.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01493/seg128000-02984552.aac
#EXTINF:5.99, no desc
01493/seg128000-02984553.aac
```

Я не могу понять, где находятся данные сегменты. Каким образом я могу получить к ним доступ, чтобы воспроизвести их, используя, к примеру NAudio MediaFoundationReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это относительные пути, они ссылаются на файлы в том же каталоге, что и список воспроизведения:

```
string baseurl = "https://digitacdn.akamaized.net/hls/live/629243/radiosuomipop/";

var mf = new MediaFoundationReader(baseurl + "01593/seg128000-03185194.aac");
```